# Not all variables bound Node js & Oracle db

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, plsql

Hi I have following PL/SQL using oracle db. When I use it.

```
        var = 'DECLARE
       IN_SCHOOL_NUM NUMBER;
       OUT_RESULTS CLOB;
       OUT_ERROR VARCHAR2(100);
       BEGIN 
       IN_SCHOOL_NUM := 3321;
       PKG.School(
       IN_SCHOOL_NUM => IN_SCHOOL_NUM,
       OUT_RESULTS => OUT_RESULTS,
       OUT_ERROR => OUT_ERROR);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(OUT_RESULTS);END'

schoolDetails(req, callback){
    oracledb.getConnection({
      user: 'xxxx',
      password:  'XXXX',
      connectString: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
      },
      function(err, conn){
         if(err) {console.error(err); return;}
         conn.execute(sql, 
            {OUT_RESULTS: {DIR: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.OBJEC}},
         function(err, result){
           if(!err){
              console.log(result.OUT_RESULTS);
              return callback(null, result)
               } else 
                console.log("error"+ err);
                return callback(err);
            }
        )}
     )}
```

When I run this I get error ORA-01008: not all variables bound.

Please let me know how to fix this issue. Thanks

Comment: You noticed that you have a typo: `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(OURT_RESULTS)` <- there is a "R" too much...

Comment: Sorry it was typo in typing. The actual code is fine no syntax errors. Thanks

Comment: Your PL/SQL in `var` doesn't have a bind variable (i.e. something prefixed with ":")  Review the node-oracledb examples at https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples and read the documentation https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#plsqlexecution  Don't forget to use the correct `type` in Node.js.  OBJECT is not a type that is usable in a bind.

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code is not a function you get something out:

```
DECLARE
       IN_SCHOOL_NUM NUMBER;
       OUT_RESULTS CLOB;
       OUT_ERROR VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN 
       IN_SCHOOL_NUM := 3321;
       PKG.School(
       OUT_RESULTS => OUT_RESULTS,
       OUT_ERROR => OUT_ERROR);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(OUT_RESULTS);
END;
```

So nothing to bind with. However my first question would be if you tried to run this in SQLDeveloper or SQLPlus? If it runs well, fine. Though `IN_SCHOOL_NUM` is totally not used anywhere.

So assuming `PKG` is a Package not a Schema I think you want to call the procedure `School` as a remote procedure from Node.

Can you also check if `School` really has no input parameter. Maybe the call should more look like:

```
PKG.School(
   IN_SCHOOL_NUM => 3321,
   OUT_RESULTS => OUT_RESULTS,
   OUT_ERROR => OUT_ERROR);
```

Because if this is the case you might get some meaningful result with change your routine to something like this:

```
        var = ' 
       PKG.School(
        IN_SCHOOL_NUM => 3321,
        OUT_RESULTS => OUT_RESULTS,
        OUT_ERROR => OUT_ERROR);'

schoolDetails(req, callback){
    oracledb.getConnection({
      user: 'xxxx',
      password:  'XXXX',
      connectString: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
      },
      function(err, conn){
         if(err) {console.error(err); return;}
         conn.execute(sql, 
            {OUT_RESULTS: {DIR: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.OBJECT}},
         function(err, result){
           if(!err){
              console.log(result.OUT_RESULTS);
              return callback(null, result)
               } else 
                console.log("error"+ err);
                return callback(err);
            }
        )}
     )}
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I was missing the IN_SCHOOL_NUM and I did add it. Please see the original code it is IN_SCHOOL_NUM => IN_SCHOOL_NUM so when I run with this it executes fine there is no error I get success but the object comes back empty. While I run same on oracle sql developer  I do get an object back.....Do you know what could be causing that? Thanks

Comment: The `declare begin end` has not result so nothing back to node.js. Is it working if you call the procedure from node.js directly like in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
'use strict';

const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const config = require('./dbconfig.js');

const myproc = `
  create or replace procedure school (
    in_school_num in number,
    out_results out clob,
    out_error out varchar2) as
  begin
    out_error := '';  -- all OUT variables should be initialized or set
    out_results := 'I done very good in class this year at school ' || IN_SCHOOL_NUM;
  end;`;

const plsql = `call school(:in_school_num_bv,:out_results_bv,:out_error_bv)`;

async function run() {
  let connection;

  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(config);

    await connection.execute(myproc);

    const binds = {
      in_school_num_bv: 123,
      out_results_bv: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT },
      out_error_bv: { type: oracledb.VARCHAR2, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT }
    };

    const result = await connection.execute(plsql, binds);

    console.log(result.outBinds.out_results_bv);
    //console.log(result.outBinds.out_error_bv);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        await connection.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

run();
```

This uses Node 8's async/await style, which is generally easier than fiddling with callbacks.